# is it possible to scroll to specific position in browsing?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser, autohotkey

I am no programmar nor tech savvy person myself.

I just wanna know if it's possible to achieve this goal:

1. The default behavior of the browser(e.g. chrome) is it sends one page up or page down depending on where I click(above or below scroll thumb).
2. But when clicking somewhere on the scroll track, I wish it navigates right through the target position in the web page.

for better understanding, here's the screenshot of cnn.com main page for reference:

[image: this is the where I will click]

[image: this is the default behavior of the browser as a result]

[image: this is what I want realize for my own convenience. it's useful when navigating through long articles]

(In first screnshot, I highlighted where I will click.

Second screenshot is the default behavior of the browser as a result.

Third screenshot is what I want realize for my own convenience. it's useful when navigating through long articles.)

I think it is almost impossible to do this on my part because maybe it's hardcoded in browser's engine level or something, but I wanted to make sure it really is.
or any workaround like making autohotkey script or something?

thank you so much!

Comment: It might need to be set system wise. At least that’s how it works on Mac

Comment: I am not mac user so no idea. but I haven't heard windows have something like that.

Comment: Since the scrollbar share the same UI with default windows apps, I would guess Chrome made its scrollbar from windows SDK, which means it would have the same behavior with all other windows apps, hence I would guess it need to be set system wise.

Comment: However I'm no expert on Windows SDK or Chrome, so I could be totally wrong.

Comment: @Ranoiaetep I quick searched google and found nothing that suggest windows might support configuring the scroll bar's default behavior. Not so much of luck lols. Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: If you just want to get to the bottom, you can probably ctrl + down, or end, and there are many plugins for that. Also not sure if you know, you can drag the scrollbar. And if you always use the windows at maxsize, you can probably do a macro, that would first point you mouse about 100 pixel down from the top right corner, then drag it to your current mouse location. Also you can set how many lines you want to scroll per mouse scroll, while I don't know the range you can set it to.

Comment: @Ranoiaetep I am thinking how to make ahk script that enables me to mess around with controlclick or click command but my goal is more than just going the distance between random spots that gives me headache.

Comment: Other than the main application window, Chrome doesn't use any native Windows controls. The scroll bars simply re-implement standard behavior. That's what users expect. There is no technical limitation to have scroll bars behave the way you want. It's just somewhat expensive to layout a web page, and the further you scroll the more layout calculations you have to perform. Expect memory and CPU spikes when jumping to random locations.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to exist [a trick with <kbd>Shift</kbd>](https://superuser.com/questions/923656/scroll-directly-where-you-click-without-keyboard-by-one-click), but it doesn't work in browsers.

However, you are manipulating a browser, and browsers have a built-in scripting language — JavaScript. Here's the setup you need to do:

1. Go to the place on the page you want to scroll to.
2. Open the developer console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> and then click on the "Console" tab). This shouldn't interfere with the scroll position.
3. Type `window.scrollY` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

After that, the console will output the amount of vertical scrolling. In the following AutoHotkey code I'll use `12345` as an example; replace it with the value you have. Note that it also scrolls to the left margin.

```
Send {F6}javascript:window.scrollTo(0,12345)`%3Bvoid`%200{Enter}
```

It appears that, due to a bug, this doesn't work in Firefox.

Answer (score -3):

I know your problem, I think chrome must have this config, you can type in the address bar "chrome://chrome-urls" for searching

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. I will def look into it and hopefully it can be configured

Comment: I have found a new solution. When you click, you do not click, but press the left mouse button, and the scroll bar will scroll to your location.